# How to navigate up a folder from My Documents in Explorer, not go back to Library folders

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer, windows-server-2008-r2

More often than not, when I go up a level from My Documents, I don't want to go back to the list of Library Folders, I want to go to the user folder that contains My Documents, Desktop, etc.

How do I force explorer to go up in the actual folder tree, rather than the virtual one created by shortcuts and symlinks.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: Windows Server 2008 R2, though I will accept an answer for W8, as if it's not the same, I can probably find equivalents from there.

Comment: I am not sure if this applies to you. You could create a new library and add your account folder to it, and use it. Once you use that library, going up one level from my documents will take you to your desired location.